# Set LTPA token in HTTP Request header

Tags: rest, http, token, ltpa

I want to invoke a REST service that is hosted on WAS.
I would like to know how to set the ltpa token in the HTTP Request header while invoking the service using SOAPUI.

Can I set the token in the Cookie field of the header?
If so, what is the format ?

Answer (score 0):

You must set this value in the cookie. My answer works on our WAS 8.5 servers. The cookie value must be:

```
LtpaToken2=<your token value goes here>
```

or

```
LtpaToken=<token here>
```

**NOTE**: you must have generated this token in the same realm as your server is running. If you have different realms, dev/test vs. production, your tokens don't work across these realms.

Be sure you have No Authentication selected in SOAPUI so you can validate that the token is working.